# Variable expansion is different in zsh from that in bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

The following is a simple test case for what I want to illustrate.

**In bash,**

```
# define the function f
f () { ls $args; }

# Runs the command `ls`
f

# Runs the fommand `ls -a`
args="-a"
f

# Runs the command `ls -a -l`
args="-a -l"
f
```

But in **zsh**

```
# define the function f
f () { ls $args }

# Runs the command `ls`
f

# Runs the fommand `ls -a`
args="-a"
f

# I expect it to run `ls -a -l`, instead it gives me an error
args="-a -l"
f
```

The last line in the zsh on above, gives me the following **error**

```
ls: invalid option -- ' '
Try `ls --help' for more information.
```

I think **zsh** is executing

```
ls "-a -l"
```

which is when I get the same error. So, how do I get bash's behavior here?

I'm not sure if I'm clear, let me know if there is something you want to know.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'd consider this better: `f () { ls "$@"; }; f -a -l`

Comment: @glenn, Yes, definitely is. As I said, this is just an illustration of a bigger problem I have, where I have to use the args variable.

Comment: @ShrikantSharat If you're writing scripts for bash and zsh (and ksh), don't do this with the `args` variable. Use an array instead.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The difference is that (by default) *zsh* does not do word splitting for unquoted parameter expansions.

You can enable “normal” word splitting by setting the SH_WORD_SPLIT option or by using the `=` flag on an individual expansion:

```
ls ${=args}
```

or

```
setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT
ls $args
```

If your target shells support arrays (*ksh*, *bash*, *zsh*), then you may be better off using an array:

```
args=(-a -l)
ls "${args[@]}"
```

---

From the [*zsh* FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/):

- [2.1: Differences from sh and ksh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#l10)

  > The classic difference is word splitting, discussed in question [3.1](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l18); this catches out very many beginning zsh users.
- [3.1: Why does $var where var="foo bar" not do what I expect?](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l18) is the FAQ that covers this question.

From the [*zsh* Manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/):

- [14.3 Parameter Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)

  > Note in particular the fact that words of unquoted parameters are not automatically split on whitespace unless the option SH_WORD_SPLIT is set; see references to this option below for more details. This is an important difference from other shells.
- [SH_WORD_SPLIT](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-SHWORDSPLIT)

  > Causes field splitting to be performed on unquoted parameter expansions.

Comment: Yes, that's just what I wanted. I didn't know what to google or where to look for, could you point to some documentation that explains this? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: All my versions of *bash* (3.2.48, and 4.2.10) reject `${=…}`. I am pretty sure is it specific to *zsh*. If you are targeting *bash* and *zsh*, then you might try an array (in my updated answer).

Comment: right, it doesn't work. am checking for zsh and using the SH_WORD_SPLIT option in a sub-shell. I wish I could use arrays, but I have to use a variable :)