# IFS in zsh behave differently than bash

Tags: bash, zsh

```
foo() {
    local lines=$(ls -l)
    local IFS=$'\n'
    for line in $lines; do
        echo $line
    done
}
```

In zsh, the loop is only executed once, because the output for `ls -l` command is not split by new lines and the entire chunk of text is passed into $line. 
In bash though, works as intended. How can I have exactly same behaviour in both shells?

I'm not looking for an alternative solutions of looping over "ls" output. Just trying to understand why it's not working in zsh but works perfectly fine in bash. Instead of "ls" command can be anything else. e.g. "ps -a". The behaviour is the same. Output is not split by line.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/74329)

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and I will accept it. 
Yes, I don't have experience in shell programming whatsoever. I'm a programmer and knowing shell programming just comes in handy. Trying to improve that area of expertise. I find it quite hard to learn it since docs are quite scattered and you have to read multiple sources even to gain most basic knowledges.

Comment: Read the dupe link, @Viorel. Issue here is quoting and you don't need to fiddle with IFS at all.

Comment: @pvg I don't know who marked the question as dupe but obviously he didn't pay any attention at all to my question. The correct answer was given by gniourf_gniourf.

Comment: @Viorel I did! I think it actually covers your case exactly as well.

Comment: @pvg No, it doesn't cover my case at all.

Comment: @Viorel i think it demonstrably does. http://i.imgur.com/Z6WjmTR.png

Comment: @pvg change echo $line to echo "line: $line" and see the results :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131476/discussion-between-viorel-and-pvg).

Comment: Why would I do that? This is your code, with two quotes added, working as described. You were missing a pair for quotes.

Comment: @pvg just to prove the output is not split into lines. 
"In zsh, the loop is only executed once, because the output for ls -l command is not split by new lines and the entire chunk of text is passed into $line."

Comment: @Viorel aha, I see what you mean. But I think in that case http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls is the right answer. You're not looking for the exact same output, you want actual filesystem traversal. Use something other than shell or call find.

Comment: I took out the dupe flag. The key thing here I think is, don't program anything that requires any degree of abstraction in shell. So both  gniourf_gniourf and Cyrus are right - just avoid the pitfall entirely.

Comment: @pvg Question is not specific to file traversal. Is about split by newline.
"I'm not looking for an alternative solutions of looping over "ls" output. Just trying to understand why it's not working in zsh but works perfectly fine in bash. Instead of "ls" command can be anything else. e.g. "ps -a". The behaviour is the same. Output is not split by line." 

Seems that gniourf_gniourf is the only one who actually understood the question.

Comment: Actually, he also told you this is a terrible idea, in more ways that can be easily counted. So if you feel they're the only one that understood you, heed their advice.

Comment: @pvg Yes he did and asked him nicely to post his answer to accept it but then you commented :)

Comment: Hah! Sorry to have distracted you. I do think the overarching point is, if you can help it (and you always can), do not program in shell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ZSH does not split words by default (like other shells):

```
foo() {
    local lines=$(ls -l)

    local IFS=$'\n'
    if [ $ZSH_VERSION ]; then
      setopt sh_word_split
    fi

    for line in $lines; do
        echo line: $line
    done
}

foo
```

Credits go to @chris-johnsen with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715447/1168315). I support his argument to better use arrays (where possible):

```
local lines=("$(ls -l)")
```

Other options would be (ZSH only):

- `local lines=("${(f)$(ls -l)}")`, where [`(f)` is shorthand for `(ps:\n:)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags)
- `for line in ${=lines}; do` (note the added equal sign)