# Zsh has totally different answer with bash

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using a zsh shell and set an environmental array.
Like this:

```
➜  ~ a=(1 2 3 4)
➜  ~ echo $a[3]
3
➜  ~ bash
%n@%m:%~%# b=(1 2 3 4 5)
%n@%m:%~%# echo $b[3]
1[3]
%n@%m:%~%# echo ${b[3]}
4
%n@%m:%~%# exit
exit
➜  ~ echo ${a[3]}
3
➜  ~
```

Colorful title is zsh while another is bash, they obviously have an opposite result. What I have read from a book about shell is like what the bash acts. So is zsh wrong? And if I write scripts for bash, would it got trouble in zsh environment? I am a newcomer for Linux , thanks if answer.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252405/102168.  The only time you will get in trouble is if you don't add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to your scripts.  Adding that line tells your shell which interpreter to use, so e.g. even if you are running `zsh` as your primary shell, you can still run scripts under `bash` with `#!/usr/bin/bash`.

Comment: @0x5453 Or better, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang.

Comment: Arrays are not standard, so each shell can implement them as they please. `zsh` is neither right nor wrong; it is just *different* from `bash`.

Comment: In addition to the reference @0x5453 gave about 1 vs 0 array indexing. The reason `$b[3]` gave you `1[3]` is because bash parsed it as `$b` followed by the plain string `[3]`. As you saw, the curly braces forced a specific parsing that included the `[3]` in the variable name. I would highly recommend *always* using curly braces whenever referencing any shell variables, even simple ones like `$foo`. If `foo=cool`, and you did: `other=$foo_bar`, expecting `other=cool_bar`, you might get surprised if `foo_bar` had also been defined in the shell.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715388/variable-expansion-is-different-in-zsh-from-that-in-bash though not strictly a duplicate. The TLDR as others have already commented is that they are different; don't expect them to be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the main question, as a rule, scripts for `zsh` should be written separately from those for `bash`. `bash` and `zsh` are both themselves, and should not be treated as two versions of the same product.

There are two reasons for what happend in your example:

1. Indexing

   - `zsh` indexes arrays from `1` to some `n`
   - `bash` indexes arrays from `0` to `n-1`
2. Syntax

   - `zsh` uses `$array[index]` syntax
   - `bash` uses `${array[index]}` syntax, and understands `$array` as access to the first element of the array, so if it is followed by anything else, the remainder is treated as a literal (that's where `1[3]` came from)

Comment: Thanks for you all, Arusekk especially. I get it.