# zsh: How can I expand a variable into multiple arguments?

Tags: bash, zsh

Here's a script that prints `foo` and `bar`, first on separate lines, then on a single line. It does that by passing two arguments to `printf`, then by passing one argument.

Finally, it passes `foo bar` using an expanded environment variable.  In that case, will `printf` see one argument or two?

```
# test.sh

echo "separate arguments:"
printf '%s\n' foo bar

echo ""
echo "combined argument"
printf '%s\n' "foo bar"

echo ""
echo "variable argument"
FOOBAR='foo bar'
printf '%s\n' ${FOOBAR}
```

It turns out `bash` and `zsh` behave differently!

Here's what `bash` does:

```
$ bash test.sh
separate arguments:
foo
bar

combined argument
foo bar

variable argument
foo
bar
```

Here's what `zsh` does:

```
$ zsh test.sh
separate arguments:
foo
bar

combined argument
foo bar

variable argument
foo bar
```

---

**Question:** Instead of writing `${FOOBAR}`, is there a syntax in `zsh` that will emulate the bash behavior?  That is, is there a syntax to expand `FOOBAR` into two arguments?

One possibility is to write `$(echo ${FOOBAR})`:

```
FOOBAR='foo bar'
printf '%s\n' $(echo ${FOOBAR})
```

...but that seems rather verbose.  Surely there's a more concise syntax?

---

PS -- Is this difference between `bash` and `zsh` documented anywhere?  I'm having trouble finding a good explanation.

Comment: Take a peek at [Variable expansion is different in zsh from that in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6715388/5291015)

Comment: This is one of the places where zsh intentionally violates the POSIX sh standard. (It's also a place where I agree with zsh's authors that POSIX sh made the wrong call; but I _disagree_ with the decision that that justifies building a shell that looks POSIX-y on the surface but has subtle incompatibilities -- better to just build a whole new language if one is going to do that).

Comment: _The difference is that (by default) zsh does not do word splitting for unquoted parameter expansions._

Comment: That said: In _both_ bash and zsh, if you want to store a list of arguments, a string is the wrong way to do it -- use an array. In either shell, this can be done with `foobar=( foo bar )`, and then `printf '%s\n' "${foobar[@]}"`

Comment: ...see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discussing why trying to use strings to store lists ends in sorrow (in bash in particular).

Comment: Thanks @Inian and Charles Duffy for the pointers.

Comment: @StuartBerg : You have to write `${(z)FOOBAR}`. If you write zsh code, think in zsh; if you write bash, think in bash. Don't mix up the two.