# Loop over space-separated string in zsh

Tags: zsh

What controls the environment to know to split by space in zsh?

I'm sure it's something simple but in all my searching have yet to figure it out what controls it.

Trying to loop over items in a space-separated string like so:

```bash
s='foo bar baz'
for i in $s; do
  echo "$i END"
done
# foo bar baz END

# ---

s='foo bar baz'
a=( $s )
echo ${a[0]} # (empty)
echo ${a[1]} # foo bar baz

# ---

s='foo bar baz'
IFS=' ' read a <<< $s
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
  echo "$i END"
done
# foo bar baz END
```

The different methods work via `sh` and `bash`, but in a shell with `oh-my-zsh` I'm unable to separate by space, getting the results above. May not be `oh-my-zsh` - but looking to understand what drives this.

Working example from bash:

```bash
s='foo bar baz'
for i in $s; do
  echo "$i END"
done
# foo END
# bar END
# baz END
```

Comment: Are you asking about zsh word splitting behaviour, and how/why it is different from the one on Bash / POSIX sh?

Comment: `oh-my-zsh` is just a framework for customizing the `zsh` shell; if you're using `oh-my-zsh`, then you're using `zsh` (not `bash`). `zsh` is significantly different from most other shells, so you need to look for documentation about `zsh`, not `bash` or any other shell (and not so much `oh-my-zsh`, because again, it's just a way of customizing `zsh`).

Comment: @BenjaminW. - yes and how to get zsh to split by word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zsh and bash are two different programming languages. They're similar, but not identical. In bash, and more generally in Bourne-style shells (`sh`, `dash`, `ksh,` …), an unquoted variable expansion `$foo` does the following:

1. Take the value of the variable `foo`, which is a string. (If there is no variable `foo`, take the empty string.)
2. Split the string into whitespace-separated parts. (More generally, the value of the `IFS` variable determines how the string is split; I won't go into all the details here.) The result is a list of strings.
3. For every element in the list, if it is a globbing pattern, i.e. if it contains at least one wildcard character `*?\[` (and possibly more depending on some shell options), and that pattern matches at least one file name, then the element is replaced by the list of matching file names. Elements that don't contain any wildcard character, and elements that contain a wildcard character but don't match any file name, are left alone. The result is again a list of strings.

Zsh is mostly a Bourne-style shell, but it has some differences, and this is the main one: `$foo` has the following, simpler behavior.

1. Take the value of the variable `foo`, which is a string. (If there is no variable `foo`, take the empty string.)
2. If this results in an empty word, this word is eliminated. (So for example `$foo$bar` is only eliminated if both `foo` and `bar` are empty or unset.)

Note that in sh or bash, `$foo` only works to split a string if it doesn't contain any wildcard character or if globbing is disabled with `set -f`.

To split a string at whitespace in zsh, there are two simple methods:

- Use the `=` [parameter expansion specified](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) to apply `IFS` word splitting. For example `$=foo` splits at whitespace as determined by `IFS`.
- Use the `p` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags). For example `${(p: :)foo}` splits at spaces (not tabs or newlines).

This has nothing to do with oh-my-zsh, which is a plugin to configure zsh for interactive use.

Comment: You can also enable word splitting of unquoted expansions with `setopt sh_word_split` in individual scripts.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, but this affects every single parameter expansion. There's hardly ever any reason to explicitly enable this option: if you need bash/sh/ksh compatibility, use `emulate`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I figured it was nothing to do with oh-my-zsh, but possibly zsh - mentioned OMZ incase it had opinionated settings but probably should have mentioned separately. Even with this explanation, setting the IFS before the `FOR - IN` loops does nothing and parameter flag expansion (`foo='bar baz'; ${(p: :)foo};`) gives error 'zsh: error in flags'. Setting the `setopt sh_word_split` works however. I'm going to research what this sets and why it's different by default.

Comment: You both lead me right to what I was looking for - the default of zsh does not do word splitting of unquoted parameter expansions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715447/9404093. Don't know how I missed that when skimming the manual.

Comment: While this answers the question you asked, what you almost certainly want to actually do instead of these suggestions is to use arrays. That would apply for a bash or ksh script too. Only in sh where there are no arrays is automatic word splitting a desirable feature but it makes it far harder to not have scripts break where e.g. filenames contain spaces.

Comment: @okapi agreed, but it's consuming stdout from a third party solution that spits out the values I need as space-separated IDs, sadly. Just making sure the script runs both locally and within the CI job it's built for.

Answer (score 2):

Just `${(p: :)foo}` didn't work for me, and was giving a a `zsh: error in flags` error. After reading [Parameter-Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) doc, I see that it should be `${(ps: :)foo}`. Even the flag `p` explanation in the doc uses the additional `s` flag.

The `p` flag doc says:

> p  : 
> Recognize the same escape sequences as the print builtin
> in string arguments to any of the flags described below
> **that follow this argument**.

So what I ended up using was just `${(s: :)foo}`. See the example for the behavior where only `space` is used as the separator, contiguous spaces are treated as one, while `tabs` and `newlines` are preserved as is:

```
> FRUITS="apple\tbanana grapes orange      passion_fruit\nwatermelon"

> for F in ${(ps: :)FRUITS}; do echo "GOT: <$F>"; done
GOT: <apple banana>
GOT: <grapes>
GOT: <orange>
GOT: <passion_fruit
watermelon>
```