# create zip file with variable in zsh (macOS)

Tags: macos, variables, zip, zsh

How can I create a zip file in zsh where I can include the appropriate files / folders by variable:

```
#!/bin/zsh
files="/var/log/install.log /var/log/jamf.log"
zip -r /private/tmp/archivtest.zip $files
```

Unfortunately this does not work in zsh, get this error message:

> zip warning: name not matched: /var/log/install.log /var/log/jamf.log
> zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r /private/tmp/archivtest.zip . -i /var/log/install.log /var/log/jamf.log)

In bash this works, but not in zsh

Comment: Please format your code more readable. Don't write everything into a single line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 - an array:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
files=(/var/log/install.log /var/log/jamf.log)
zip -r /private/tmp/archivtest.zip $files
```

Option 2 - the `=` operator:

```
#!/bin/zsh
files="/var/log/install.log /var/log/jamf.log"
zip -r /private/tmp/archivtest.zip ${=files}
```

In `zsh`, variables are not automatically split on spaces, unlike `bash`. There's a very good explanation of the differences between the shells [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361957) - the section titled "Main differences for scripting" describes the handling of spaces in more detail. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715447) has links to the documentation on word splitting, including this [FAQ](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l18).