# SLURM and Docker, accessing reserved GPUs not working with zsh

Tags: docker, zsh, slurm

I'm running docker containers on a server using SLURM.

Generally, I connect to a manager node, and run my jobs on one of the other nodes by using:

```
srun -w gpu02 --gres="gpu:xxx:1" --cpus-per-task=16 --pty /bin/bash
```

Once I'm connected to the required node, I can see only the reserved GPU by running nvidia-smi:

```
Fri Sep 29 08:09:07 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.125.06   Driver Version: 525.125.06   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A30          On   | 00000000:CA:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P0    29W / 165W |      0MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

On the node, there is an environmental variable $DOCKER_GPUS set to:

```
echo $DOCKER_GPUS
--gpus all --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm-tools --device=/dev/nvidiactl --device /dev/nvidia2
```

so that I can use it to run a Docker container accessing only the GPU reserved through SLURM:

```
docker run --name container_name -it -d --rm $DOCKER_GPUS image_name
```

and everything works fine, the container has only access to the required GPU.

My issue is that, if I try to do the same using zshell, this doesn't work.
So, I launch the SLURM job by:

```
srun -w gpu02 --gres="gpu:A30:1" --cpus-per-task=16 --pty /usr/bin/zsh
```

Once I'm in the node, the environmental variable is still set:

```
echo $SR_DOCKER_GPUS
--gpus all --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm-tools --device=/dev/nvidiactl --device /dev/nvidia2
```

but now, if try to run the container as before:

```
docker run --name container_name -it -d --rm $DOCKER_GPUS image_name
```

I get the error:

```
unknown flag: --gpus all --device
See 'docker run --help'.
```

It's like, when using zsh, the content of the env variable DOCKER_GPUS is not parsed correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715447 https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097073

Comment: In the zsh-case, you didn't word split. Write `${(z)DOCKER_GPUS}` instead.

Comment: Aside from this, it would make much more sense to turn `DOCKER_GPUS` into an array. This could safe you headaches in the future.