# expanding variable in zsh

Tags: zsh

In a bash environment, if the statement

```bash
export FC="gfortran -O3 -ffree-line-length-none"
```

is added to the .bashrc file, then in a terminal, the command

```bash
$FC main.f90
```

will compile program `main.f90` and produce an executable named `a.out`.
This is a simple example but in general there might be more than two options passed to a program (`gfortran` in this example).
If the above export statement is placed in a .zshrc file,
the command `$FC main.f90` fails and gives the following msg:

```
zsh: command not found: gfortran -O3 -ffree-line-length-none
```

Is there a syntax in zsh that replicates what happens in bash or another way to do it in zsh?

Comment: Why not use a function?

Comment: Try using standard aliases rather than export. Do ```alias FC="gfortran -O3 -ffree-line-length-none"```

Comment: Zsh has nonstandard handling of quotes. Try without quotes around the assignment (or stick to a Bourne-compatible shell like Bash).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097073. You can use an array `FC=(...)` or `${=FC} main.f90`.

Comment: Karnik Kanojia: Brilliant. Simple. It works.

Comment: Beside the point, but [in Bash, strings containing commands are also not recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create zip file with variable in zsh (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096844/create-zip-file-with-variable-in-zsh-macos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a straightforward alias without the export as in

alias FC="gfortran -O3 -ffree-line-length-none"

FC main.f90

is the simplest solution and works for me.
Thanks to Karnik Kanojia for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Word splitting occurs early, and variable expansion occurs pretty late in zsh. The shell therefore sees $FC as command to be executed, and the content of `FC` is the command name.

bash OTOH expands the variable first, and then does word splitting.

You could do a `${(z)FC}` in zsh for your concrete case. The `(z)` tells zsh to do work splitting on the expanded string.

However, in gerneral you are safer to make `FC` and array. The first element would be the command name and each subsequent array element would be a command argument. In this way, you can even pass command arguments which contain white space..

Comment: By default, word-splitting is not applied to parameter expansions at all in `zsh`, unlike in `bash`. (Don't confuse word-splitting, which is based the value of `IFS`, with the earlier parsing step that uses whitespace specifically to recognize words initially.)