# Why is the same command in a Z shell script interpreted differently than when directly run in a Z shell shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, python-poetry

I have written a helper script (Z shell (executable `zsh`) dialect) that installs Python's Poetry package manager. A weird problem occurs where the same shell command is interpreted differently, when run (a) in a shell script vs (b) directly in Z shell. An excerpt of the script is this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -x
INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION="--version 1.6.1"
# Why does this not work?
echo "curl -sSL URL | python3 - $INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION"
# will print:
# curl -sSL URL | python3 - --version 1.6.1
curl -sSL URL | python3 - "$INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION"
# The fix I use which works but I don't understand why, is:
# curl -sSL URL | python3 - $(printf "%s" "$INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION")
set +x
```

Here is the result when the shell script is executed:

```
➜  /usr/bin/zsh test_script.zsh
+test_script.zsh:3> INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION='--version 1.6.1'
+test_script.zsh:5> echo 'curl -sSL URL | python3 - --version 1.6.1'
curl -sSL URL | python3 - --version 1.6.1
+test_script.zsh:8> curl -sSL URL
+test_script.zsh:8> python3 - '--version 1.6.1'
usage: - [-h] [-p] [--version VERSION] [-f] [-y] [--uninstall] [--path PATH] [--git GIT]
-: error: unrecognized arguments: --version 1.6.1
+test_script.zsh:9> set +x
```

The argument `--version 1.6.1` can not be interpreted by remotely called shell script.

When I call the printed (echo) cmd in Z shell it works fine. See:

```
➜  /usr/bin/zsh -c "curl -sSL URL | python3 - --version 1.6.1"
Retrieving Poetry metadata

The latest version (1.6.1) is already installed.
```

My current fix in the shell file is this:

```
# The fix I use which works but I don't understand why, is:
curl -sSL URL | python3 - $(printf "%s" "$INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION")
```

How come the variable's value is passed/interpreted differently. What am I missing here?

Z shell version: 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)

Comment: Because `python3 - "$var"` is only receiving 2 params (`-` and the value of `$var`) while `python3 - --version 1.6.1` is running python with 3 params (`-`, `--version`, and `1.6.1`). Your script and your interactive calls are not equivalent: the equivalent interactive call is `python3 - '--version 1.6.1'`

Comment: You shouldn't store commands (or parts of commands) in variables: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5615717/112968

Comment: Your "fix" (it's not a fix) is a convoluted way of writing `python3 - $INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION`

Comment: Thanks @knittl for your clarification. So I understand that the single quote makes the problem. I am not storing a command. I am trying to make the version string configurable. The original script uses a command argument `test_script.zsh '--version 1.6.1'`. I have used the variable for demonstration purposes.

How do I concatenate the python command with the variables (argument's) value without the single quote then?

Comment: The suggestion that my convoluted way of writing: `python3 - $INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION` does not seem to hold true as the command is equally not working. Did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: Your suggestion does work though, when I remove the quotes from the variable definition: `INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION=--version 1.6.1`. I would answer the question like this if it is that what you meant. Fee free to add another answer.

Comment: `INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION=--version 1.6.1` is nonsense and you should get an error _zsh: command not found: 1.6.1_ . In general, if you write something like `A=B C`, zsh tries to run the program `C` in an environment, where the variable `A` is set to value `B`.

Comment: Side note: the preferred installation method for poetry was [recently changed](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/releases/tag/1.7.0) from the official installer to using `pipx`. With `pipx`, you can just use `pipx install poetry==$DESIRED_VERSION`, which doesn't suffer from this issue.

Comment: Related: [Variable expansion is different in zsh from that in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715388/variable-expansion-is-different-in-zsh-from-that-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (sensibly nor sanely) store multiple words (arguments, commends, etc) in a single variable. What you can do however, is to [expand a parameter with an alternative value](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) containing a single word:

> `${parameter:+word}`
> **Use Alternative Value.** If parameter is unset or null, null shall be substituted; otherwise, the expansion of word shall be substituted.

In your case:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
# you don't need zsh for this, plain sh works just fine
INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION="1.6.1"
curl -sSL URL | python3 - ${INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION:+--version "$INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION"}
```

This will expand to *nothing* if the parameter is not set to a value and expand to *two* words `--version` and `1.6.1` if the parameter contains a value.

Alternatively, use plain old `if`:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION="1.6.1"
if test "$INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION"; then
  curl -sSL URL | python3 - --version "$INSTALL_SPECIFIC_VERSION"
else
  curl -sSL URL | python3 -
fi
```

Here's why you always want to quote your parameter expansions: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). Running arbitrary commands from a remote server is also security-critical and should be avoided if possible (but sometimes there's no way around it).

Resources:

- [How can I store a command in a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-can-i-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: IIRC, there _is_ a flag that can be used during parameter expansion in zsh to force it to do word-splitting. Certainly better to avoid that in favor of the approaches shown here, though.